# Is there another library I have missed before running chatterbot?

Tags: chatterbot

I've tried to create a chatbot program using the chatterbot library. It produced some errors which beat all attempts to resolve. Finally, I went to the chatterbot documentation online and copy/pasted the first example chatterbot code and run it in my editor. This produced the same errors. So I want to know if there is some library I have missed perhaps, what that library is and the version of the library to install?

I've run the example code from `https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html` Simple Example (as found below). It has produced the same errors.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

# Create a new chat bot named Charlie
chatbot = ChatBot('Charlie')

trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)

trainer.train([
    "Hi, can I help you?",
    "Sure, I'd like to book a flight to Iceland.",
    "Your flight has been booked."
])

# Get a response to the input text 'I would like to book a flight.'
response = chatbot.get_response('I would like to book a flight.')

print(response)
```

I expect to have a prompt at the terminal that allows input and produces a response. I got a list of error instead.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ikwame.amofa/PycharmProjects/trychat/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "/Users/ikwame.amofa/PycharmProjects/trychat/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "/Users/ikwame.amofa/PycharmProjects/trychat/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/chatterbot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from chatterbot.storage import StorageAdapter
  File "/Users/ikwame.amofa/PycharmProjects/trychat/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/storage/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatterbot.storage.storage_adapter import StorageAdapter
  File "/Users/ikwame.amofa/PycharmProjects/trychat/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/storage/storage_adapter.py", line 3, in <module>
    from chatterbot.tagging import PosHypernymTagger
  File "/Users/ikwame.amofa/PycharmProjects/trychat/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/tagging.py", line 4, in <module>
    from chatterbot.tokenizers import get_sentence_tokenizer
  File "/Users/ikwame.amofa/PycharmProjects/trychat/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/tokenizers.py", line 4, in <module>
    from chatterbot.corpus import load_corpus, list_corpus_files
  File "/Users/ikwame.amofa/PycharmProjects/trychat/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/corpus.py", line 5, in <module>
    from chatterbot_corpus.corpus import DATA_DIRECTORY
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot_corpus'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put your error message in a code tag,

Secondly, you forgot to install the library. Install it using:

`pip install chatterbot-coprus`